# How to avoid values from spilling over two lines when I export data from mysql to Ms Word using php?

Tags: php

I am building an application in PHP and MySQL that manages insurance agencies, now my application is supposed to print insurance certificates but when i try to do it directly from the browser the quality of the words is too blurred so in decided to export that data to MsWord, when I do that, some of the data is spilling over two lines when it opens in word and this is a problem since I cant print it into a certificate without the proper alignments, here is my code

```
<?php
 ob_end_clean();
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=test.doc");

 $g=mysqli_query($con,("select  concat_ws(' ',fir,sur)as name,phone,clie.cli_id,prem.comp_name,prem.pre_id,cover,cert_serial,pol_num,exp_date,py_date, tr_date,Reg_number from clie inner join vehicle using(cli_id)inner join prem using(cli_id) inner join pre_pay using(pre_id) where pre_id='$id' order by tr_date desc limit 1"));
      if(mysqli_num_rows($g)==1){
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($g)){
             echo'<table><style> td{font-family:Times New Roman;
padding: 0px;
background-color: white;
-moz-border-radius: ;
nowrap;
font-size:62.5%}</style>
      <tr><b><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></td></tr>

        <tr><b><td>'.$row['pol_num'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['pol_num'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['pol_num'].'</td></tr>

<tr><b><td>'.$row['py_date'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td>00.00H</td><td></td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['py_date'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td>00.00H</td><td></td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['py_date'].'<td></td><td></td><td>00.00H</td></td></tr>

 <tr><b><td>'.$row['exp_date'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['exp_date'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['exp_date'].'</td></tr>

         <tr><b><td>'.$row['Reg_number'].''.$row['cover'].'</td><td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['Reg_number'].''.$row['cover'].'</td><td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['Reg_number'].''.$row['cover'].'</td></tr>

          <tr><b><td>'.$row['comp_name'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['comp_name'].'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>'.$row['comp_name'].'</td></tr>';    
          }
          echo'</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

hi everyone it seems weird but i have to answer my own question, after struggling with this problem for weeks i found that i actually don't need to export any data to Ms word at all, but it's actually possible to print directly from the browser and get the right quality as demanded by the client, this solution however, only works properly with with a chrome browser, i only had to specify specific font family rules in css that affect table data resp. here is the solution i found...

```
`echo'<div align="center"><br /><a href="javascript:void(processPrint());"> <input type="image" value=<img src="images/print.png"/></a>
<div id="printMe">';
$q=mysqli_query($con,("select concat_ws('  ',fir,las)as name, id,clie.cli_id,prem.comp_name,pol_num,cert_serial,exp_date,py_date,amnt, Reg_number from clie inner join vehicle using(cli_id)inner join prem using(cli_id)inner join pre_pay using(pre_id) where pre_id='$id' limit 1"));
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($q);
$name=$row['name'];
$ve=$row['Reg_number'];
$p=$row['id'];
$co=$row['comp_name'];
$pa=$row['py_date'];
$exp=$row['exp_date'];
$paid=$row['amnt'];
$cer=$row['cert_serial'];
$po=$row['pol_num'];`

`$g=mysqli_query($con,("select  concat_ws('  ',fir,sur)as name,phone,clie.cli_id,prem.comp_name,prem.pre_id,cover,cert_serial,pol_num,exp_date,py_date, tr_date,Reg_number from clie inner join vehicle using(cli_id)inner join prem using(cli_id) inner join pre_pay using(pre_id) where pre_id='$id' order by tr_date desc limit 1"));`




      if(mysqli_num_rows($g)==1){

          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($g)){


     echo'<table><style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Times New Roman;font-size: 10px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: white;
-moz-border-radius: ;
nowrap;

      <tr><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Times New Roman;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['name'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['name'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></b></tr>


        <tr><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['pol_num'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['pol_num'].'</b></td><td><td></td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['pol_num'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></b></tr>

        <tr><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['py_date'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>00.00H</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['py_date'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>00.00H</b></td><td></td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['py_date'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>00.00H</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>


         <tr><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['exp_date'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['exp_date'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['exp_date'].'</b></td></b></tr>

         <tr><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['Reg_number'].''.$row['cover'].'</b></td><td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['Reg_number'].''.$row['cover'].'</b></td><td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td><td><td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['Reg_number'].''.$row['cover'].'</b></td></b></tr>


          <tr><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['comp_name'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['comp_name'].'</b></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="font-family:Bell Gothic ,Verdana,Arial;font-size: 10px;"><b>'.$row['comp_name'].'</b></td></b></tr>';    
          }
          echo'</style></table>';
      }else{
          echo'<p>No records found</p>';
      }
```